# X.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one X -- it returned 2

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a model, Chapter, linked to the Book model through a ForeignKey.
One of it's fields, the integer field, number, is "slugified" to make the slug field, chapter_slug.

The problem is my DetailView. When I call it the error "raise self.model.MultipleObjectsReturned(books.models.Chapter.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Chapter -- it returned 2!"

That happens when I have more than one chapter 1, in this case, in two different books.

```
class Chapter(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    number = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    chapter_slug = models.SlugField(null=True)
    ...

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('chapter', kwargs={'book_slug': self.book.book_slug, 'chapter_slug': self.chapter_slug})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.chapter_slug:
            self.chapter_slug = slugify(self.number)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    ...
```

```
path('book/<slug:book_slug>/chapter/<slug:chapter_slug>/', views.ChapterView.as_view(), name='chapter'),
```

```
class ChapterView(DetailView):
    model = Chapter
    template_name = books/chapter.html'
    context_object_name = 'chapter'
    slug_field = 'chapter_slug'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'chapter_slug'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        chapter = self.get_object()
        context['book_slug'] = chapter.book.book_slug
        context['chapter_slug'] = chapter.chapter_slug
        ...
```

```
[08/Apr/2023 15:43:03] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 79
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[08/Apr/2023 15:43:03] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 9214
[08/Apr/2023 15:43:14] "GET /book/example/chapter/1 HTTP/1.1" 301 0
Internal Server Error: /book/example/chapter/1/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 103, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 142, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py", line 108, in get
    self.object = self.get_object()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py", line 53, in get_object
    obj = queryset.get()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 653, in get
    raise self.model.MultipleObjectsReturned(
books.models.Chapter.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Chapter -- it returned 2!
[08/Apr/2023 15:43:14] "GET /book/example/chapter/1/ HTTP/1.1" 500 82252
```

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please edit the question to add the full error traceback message.

Comment: In general, it's up to you to call `.get()` with query values that will result in exactly one object being found.  If `Chapter.id` is not unique, then you have to pass additional fields to `.get()`, enough to narrow it down to one specific chapter.  (Perhaps also pass the Book instance?)

Comment: I can't call .get() with query values that will result in one object being found because request isn't defined.

Comment: The error is in the view. It is the model = Chapter line. It gets two objects because the slug is the same. To solve the problem I tried calling get() but request is not defined and I got an error. How am I making you guess where the error is?

Comment: The post title refers to the MultipleObjectsReturned error.  The code you posted can't possibly have that particular error, because it has a different one (requests is not defined.)  So, the post title refers to unknown code that you haven't shown us.  THAT is how you're making us guess.

Comment: The post title refers to MultipleObjectsReturned error because that's the main error.
In the second paragraph of my post I say that that is my problem and it arises when I call the DetailView.

The request is not defined is the error I got when I tried to solve the problem, They're different errors.

I removed from the post the part where I talked about what I tried to do to solve the problem since it was causing confusion.

Comment: And in the code as it now stands, there is no call to `.get()` at all, so once again you're making us guess where the error happens...

Comment: There is no .get() function that I call but there still is a raise self.model.MultipleObjectsReturned(books.models.Chapter.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Chapter -- it returned 2! error.

I have already pasted all the code I have that is related to the error.
The .get() function might be called in model = Chapter.

Comment: Seeing the full error traceback might help us understand how the error happens.  By withholding the error traceback, you're making it harder for us to help you.  I don't understand why you would ask for help, and then make it harder for us to actually help.

Comment: I've added the full error traceback.

Comment: I see that `book_slug` is part of the url.  Why doesn't the view use it?  Would the combination of `book` and `chapter_slug` be enough to uniquely identify a Chapter object?

Comment: The view needs to use it in order for me to go to the url, it is in the get_context_data method. I've edited the post and added it.